# How do I run a shell script without using “sh” command?

Tags: php, shell, sh

I have an sh file which executes a php file. I'm trying to run it without using sh command. I want to run it using the command test.sh and not "sh test.sh".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hashbang as the first line of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Then set it as executable:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Then you should be able to run it with `./test.sh`.